# Thorntail app on Heroku with JVM metrics enabled

Tags: heroku, thorntail

When I enable Heroku's JVM metrics on my working Thorntail 2.2.0 app, the app fails at startup, and strange errors occur...

Obviously, it has something to do with :

```
2018-10-08T19:11:34.512200+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/app/.heroku/bin/heroku-metrics-agent.jar
```

Any idea ?

Here is the full startup log :

```
2018-10-08T19:10:52.554331+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-10-08T19:11:30.516536+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xmx224m -Xss512k -Dswarm.datasources.data-sources.XXX.connection-url=jdbc:mysql://XXX/XXX                                              -Dswarm.datasources.data-sources.XXX.driver-name=mysql                                         -Dswarm.datasources.data-sources.XXX.user-name=XXX                      -Dswarm.datasources.data-sources.XXX.password=XXX                                      -Dswarm.datasources.data-sources.XXX.validate-on-match=true -Dswarm.datasources.data-sources.XXX.background-validation=true  "-Dswarm.http.port=8366" -jar adi-web/XXX-webapp/build/libs/XXX-webapp-hollow-thorntail.jar XXX-web/XXX-webapp/build/libs/XXX.war`
2018-10-08T19:11:34.141406+00:00 app[web.1]: [heroku-exec] Starting
2018-10-08T19:11:34.512200+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/app/.heroku/bin/heroku-metrics-agent.jar 
2018-10-08T19:12:35.905056+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:35 PM org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.ServerBootstrapImpl logFraction
2018-10-08T19:12:35.905064+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: THORN0013: Installed fraction:                   JAX-RS - STABLE          io.thorntail:jaxrs:2.2.0.Final
2018-10-08T19:12:35.908249+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:35 PM org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.ServerBootstrapImpl logFraction
2018-10-08T19:12:35.908256+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: THORN0013: Installed fraction:                  Logging - STABLE          io.thorntail:logging:2.2.0.Final
2018-10-08T19:12:35.925744+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:35 PM org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.ServerBootstrapImpl logFraction
2018-10-08T19:12:35.925748+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: THORN0013: Installed fraction:                  Elytron - STABLE          io.thorntail:elytron:2.2.0.Final
2018-10-08T19:12:35.935554+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:35 PM org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.ServerBootstrapImpl logFraction
2018-10-08T19:12:35.935558+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: THORN0013: Installed fraction:                      JPA - STABLE          io.thorntail:jpa:2.2.0.Final
2018-10-08T19:12:35.946180+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:35 PM org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.ServerBootstrapImpl logFraction
2018-10-08T19:12:35.946183+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: THORN0013: Installed fraction:                 Undertow - STABLE          io.thorntail:undertow:2.2.0.Final
2018-10-08T19:12:35.984719+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:35 PM org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.ServerBootstrapImpl logFraction
2018-10-08T19:12:35.984724+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: THORN0013: Installed fraction:          Bean Validation - STABLE          io.thorntail:bean-validation:2.2.0.Final
2018-10-08T19:12:35.998796+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:35 PM org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.ServerBootstrapImpl logFraction
2018-10-08T19:12:35.998800+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: THORN0013: Installed fraction:                      JCA - STABLE          io.thorntail:jca:2.2.0.Final
2018-10-08T19:12:36.020240+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:36 PM org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.ServerBootstrapImpl logFraction
2018-10-08T19:12:36.020244+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: THORN0013: Installed fraction:             Transactions - STABLE          io.thorntail:transactions:2.2.0.Final
2018-10-08T19:12:36.028312+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:36 PM org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.ServerBootstrapImpl logFraction
2018-10-08T19:12:36.028317+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: THORN0013: Installed fraction:                      JSF - STABLE          io.thorntail:jsf:2.2.0.Final
2018-10-08T19:12:36.032955+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:36 PM org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.ServerBootstrapImpl logFraction
2018-10-08T19:12:36.032959+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: THORN0013: Installed fraction:        CDI Configuration - STABLE          io.thorntail:cdi-config:2.2.0.Final
2018-10-08T19:12:36.047870+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:36 PM org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.ServerBootstrapImpl logFraction
2018-10-08T19:12:36.047874+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: THORN0013: Installed fraction:                      CDI - STABLE          io.thorntail:cdi:2.2.0.Final
2018-10-08T19:12:36.088953+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:36 PM org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.ServerBootstrapImpl logFraction
2018-10-08T19:12:36.088957+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: THORN0013: Installed fraction:                      EJB - STABLE          io.thorntail:ejb:2.2.0.Final
2018-10-08T19:12:36.095022+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:36 PM org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.ServerBootstrapImpl logFraction
2018-10-08T19:12:36.095026+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: THORN0013: Installed fraction:              Datasources - STABLE          io.thorntail:datasources:2.2.0.Final
2018-10-08T19:12:36.101204+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:36 PM org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.ServerBootstrapImpl logFraction
2018-10-08T19:12:36.101208+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: THORN0013: Installed fraction:       JAX-RS with JSON-P - STABLE          io.thorntail:jaxrs-jsonp:2.2.0.Final
2018-10-08T19:12:36.102051+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:36 PM org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.ServerBootstrapImpl logFraction
2018-10-08T19:12:36.102054+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: THORN0013: Installed fraction:    JAX-RS with Multipart - STABLE          io.thorntail:jaxrs-multipart:2.2.0.Final
2018-10-08T19:12:36.131170+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:36 PM org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.ServerBootstrapImpl logFraction
2018-10-08T19:12:36.131174+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: THORN0013: Installed fraction:                      Web - STABLE          io.thorntail:web:2.2.0.Final
2018-10-08T19:12:36.137655+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:36 PM org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.ServerBootstrapImpl logFraction
2018-10-08T19:12:36.137659+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: THORN0013: Installed fraction:      Hibernate Validator - STABLE          io.thorntail:hibernate-validator:2.2.0.Final
2018-10-08T19:12:36.156735+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:36 PM org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.ServerBootstrapImpl logFraction
2018-10-08T19:12:36.156772+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: THORN0013: Installed fraction:   JAX-RS with Validation - STABLE          io.thorntail:jaxrs-validator:2.2.0.Final
2018-10-08T19:12:36.162066+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:36 PM org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.ServerBootstrapImpl logFraction
2018-10-08T19:12:36.162070+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: THORN0013: Installed fraction:         JAX-RS with JAXB - STABLE          io.thorntail:jaxrs-jaxb:2.2.0.Final
2018-10-08T19:12:36.977514+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:36 PM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup 
2018-10-08T19:12:36.977528+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: WELD-000900: 2.4.3 (Final)
2018-10-08T19:12:37.024143+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:37 PM org.jboss.weld.util.ServiceLoader loadClass
2018-10-08T19:12:37.024151+00:00 app[web.1]: WARNING: Could not load service class org.wildfly.swarm.cdi.config.deployment.InjectConfigViewExtension
2018-10-08T19:12:37.062068+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:37 PM org.jboss.weld.environment.deployment.discovery.DiscoveryStrategyFactory create
2018-10-08T19:12:37.062074+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: WELD-ENV-000020: Using jandex for bean discovery
2018-10-08T19:12:41.971025+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:41 PM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup startContainer
2018-10-08T19:12:41.971044+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: WELD-000101: Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously.
2018-10-08T19:12:47.095661+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:47 PM org.jboss.weld.interceptor.reader.InterceptorMetadataUtils isValidTargetClassLifecycleInterceptorMethod
2018-10-08T19:12:47.095675+00:00 app[web.1]: WARN: WELD-001471: Interceptor method postConstruct defined on class org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.wildfly.ShrinkWrapFileSystem is not defined according to the specification. It should not throw java.io.IOException, which is a checked exception.
2018-10-08T19:12:47.095678+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.wildfly.ShrinkWrapFileSystem.postConstruct(ShrinkWrapFileSystem.java:0)
2018-10-08T19:12:47.095680+00:00 app[web.1]:   StackTrace
2018-10-08T19:12:47.097952+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:47 PM org.jboss.weld.interceptor.reader.InterceptorMetadataUtils isValidTargetClassLifecycleInterceptorMethod
2018-10-08T19:12:47.097963+00:00 app[web.1]: WARN: WELD-001471: Interceptor method setupFactories defined on class org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.xmlconfig.StandaloneXMLParserProducer is not defined according to the specification. It should not throw java.lang.Exception, which is a checked exception.
2018-10-08T19:12:47.097966+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.xmlconfig.StandaloneXMLParserProducer.setupFactories(StandaloneXMLParserProducer.java:0)
2018-10-08T19:12:47.097968+00:00 app[web.1]:   StackTrace
2018-10-08T19:12:47.461880+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:47 PM org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldContainer fireContainerInitializedEvent
2018-10-08T19:12:47.461891+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: WELD-ENV-002003: Weld SE container internal initialized
2018-10-08T19:12:49.530773+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:49 PM org.wildfly.swarm.datasources.runtime.DatasourceAndDriverCustomizer attemptInstallation
2018-10-08T19:12:49.530785+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: THORN1003: Auto-detected JDBC driver for mysql
2018-10-08T19:12:52.625954+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:52 PM org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl 
2018-10-08T19:12:52.625973+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: JBoss MSC version 1.2.7.SP1
2018-10-08T19:12:52.975271+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:52 PM org.jboss.as.server.ApplicationServerService start
2018-10-08T19:12:52.975283+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: WFLYSRV0049: Thorntail 2.2.0.Final (WildFly Core 3.0.8.Final) starting
2018-10-08T19:12:53.350956+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:53 PM org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.cli.CommandLineArgsServiceActivator activate
2018-10-08T19:12:53.350968+00:00 app[web.1]: INFO: THORN0019: Install MSC service for command line args: [XXX-web/XXX-webapp/build/libs/XXX.war]
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444531+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:57 PM org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext executeStep
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444543+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR: WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("parallel-extension-add") failed - address: ([])
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444545+00:00 app[web.1]: java.lang.RuntimeException: WFLYCTL0079: Failed initializing module org.jboss.as.logging
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444551+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ParallelExtensionAddHandler$1.execute(ParallelExtensionAddHandler.java:115)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444553+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:980)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444554+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:726)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444556+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:450)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444557+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1402)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444559+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:490)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444560+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:468)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444562+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:430)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444563+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:437)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444565+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:396)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444567+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:370)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444569+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444572+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYLOG0078: The logging subsystem requires the log manager to be org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager. The subsystem has not be initialized and cannot be used. To use JBoss Log Manager you must add the system property "java.util.logging.manager" and set it to "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444574+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444576+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444577+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ParallelExtensionAddHandler$1.execute(ParallelExtensionAddHandler.java:107)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444580+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 11 more
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444582+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYLOG0078: The logging subsystem requires the log manager to be org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager. The subsystem has not be initialized and cannot be used. To use JBoss Log Manager you must add the system property "java.util.logging.manager" and set it to "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager"
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444584+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.as.logging.LoggingExtension.initialize(LoggingExtension.java:167)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444585+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ExtensionAddHandler.initializeExtension(ExtensionAddHandler.java:131)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444587+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ExtensionAddHandler.initializeExtension(ExtensionAddHandler.java:104)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444594+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ParallelExtensionAddHandler$ExtensionInitializeTask.call(ParallelExtensionAddHandler.java:144)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444596+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.as.controller.extension.ParallelExtensionAddHandler$ExtensionInitializeTask.call(ParallelExtensionAddHandler.java:127)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444597+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444599+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444601+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444602+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444604+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.444605+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-10-08T19:12:57.550906+00:00 app[web.1]: Oct 08, 2018 7:12:57 PM org.jboss.as.server.ServerService$4 logExit
2018-10-08T19:12:57.550914+00:00 app[web.1]: FATAL: WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
2018-10-08T19:12:57.610496+00:00 app[web.1]: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Operation failed
2018-10-08T19:12:57.613703+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.wildfly.swarm.spi.api.ClassLoading.withTCCL(ClassLoading.java:45)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.613954+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.ServerBootstrapImpl.bootstrap(ServerBootstrapImpl.java:113)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.614003+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.start(Swarm.java:398)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.614071+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.main(Swarm.java:742)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.614650+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.614695+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.614734+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.615007+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.615056+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.MainInvoker.invoke(MainInvoker.java:53)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.616224+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.run(Main.java:132)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.616292+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.main(Main.java:85)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.616664+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Operation failed
2018-10-08T19:12:57.617097+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.threads.AsyncFutureTask.operationFailed(AsyncFutureTask.java:74)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.617154+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.threads.AsyncFutureTask.get(AsyncFutureTask.java:268)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.617431+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.wildfly.swarm.internal.wildfly.SelfContainedContainer.start(SelfContainedContainer.java:147)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.617478+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeServer.start(RuntimeServer.java:213)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.617676+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeServer$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.start(Unknown Source)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.679602+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.ServerBootstrapImpl.lambda$bootstrap$1(ServerBootstrapImpl.java:159)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.679933+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.wildfly.swarm.spi.api.ClassLoading.withTCCL(ClassLoading.java:43)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.679972+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 10 more
2018-10-08T19:12:57.683415+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.Exception: WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
2018-10-08T19:12:57.683485+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.as.server.BootstrapListener.bootFailure(BootstrapListener.java:87)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.683530+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:417)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.683561+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:370)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.683597+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.683704+00:00 app[web.1]: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Operation failed
2018-10-08T19:12:57.683756+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.wildfly.swarm.spi.api.ClassLoading.withTCCL(ClassLoading.java:45)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.683786+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.ServerBootstrapImpl.bootstrap(ServerBootstrapImpl.java:113)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.683821+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.start(Swarm.java:398)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.683880+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.wildfly.swarm.Swarm.main(Swarm.java:742)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.683942+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.684004+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.684034+00:00 app[web.1]:    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.684088+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.684136+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.MainInvoker.invoke(MainInvoker.java:53)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.684184+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.run(Main.java:132)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.684223+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.wildfly.swarm.bootstrap.Main.main(Main.java:85)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.684272+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: Operation failed
2018-10-08T19:12:57.684310+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.threads.AsyncFutureTask.operationFailed(AsyncFutureTask.java:74)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.684352+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.threads.AsyncFutureTask.get(AsyncFutureTask.java:268)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.684416+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.wildfly.swarm.internal.wildfly.SelfContainedContainer.start(SelfContainedContainer.java:147)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.684450+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeServer.start(RuntimeServer.java:213)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.684480+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.RuntimeServer$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.start(Unknown Source)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.684522+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.wildfly.swarm.container.runtime.ServerBootstrapImpl.lambda$bootstrap$1(ServerBootstrapImpl.java:159)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.684560+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.wildfly.swarm.spi.api.ClassLoading.withTCCL(ClassLoading.java:43)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.684611+00:00 app[web.1]:    ... 10 more
2018-10-08T19:12:57.706797+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.Exception: WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
2018-10-08T19:12:57.706835+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.as.server.BootstrapListener.bootFailure(BootstrapListener.java:87)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.706895+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:417)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.706952+00:00 app[web.1]:    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:370)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.707004+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-10-08T19:12:57.969309+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-10-08T19:12:57.986184+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: Essentially if the JMX agent is started first it takes over the logging, which causes Thorntail to fail to start. There was a similar issue with Jolokia usage that required a fix in Jolokia: https://github.com/rhuss/jolokia/pull/260

Comment: did anyone find a solution to this? I'm on the same boat and wish to startup a jmx agent but am getting the same error